# Specifying a generic constraint that depends on another generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have something along the lines of the following:

```
// This part is fine
abstract class Attack {}

abstract class Unit<A> where A : Attack {}

class InstantAttack : Attack {}
class Infantry : Unit<InstantAttack> {}

// I'm lost here, on this part's syntax:
abstract class Controller<U> where U : Unit {}
// I want the above class to take any kind of Unit, but Unit is a generic class!
```

The above doesn't work for `Controller`, because `where U : Unit` isn't right since `Unit` requires a generic parameter (like `Unit<InstantAttack>`). I tried:

```
abstract class Controller<U<A>> where U<A> : Unit<A> {}
```

which certainly didn't work. What's the correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either like this:

```
abstract class Controller<U, A> where U : Unit<A> {}
```

Or like this:

```
interface IUnit { }
abstract class Unit<A> : IUnit where A : Attack { }
abstract class Controller<U> where U : IUnit { }
```